# Running Perl Script from JavaFx

Tags: perl, javafx

I'm trying to run a Perl script from a JavaFx stage when a button is pressed.

I'm able to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to run the script in the `public static void main(String[] args)` method of the main class, but when doing this it doesn't run until the `Application.launch(args)` is completed. I want it to run while the stage is still active instead of having to close it.

I tried adding it to the `ButtonHandlerClass` as part of the `public void handle(ActionEvent e)` method with no luck.

Comment: I think `public static void main()` is a redundant method when JavaFX is running using the `Application.launch()` process. `exec` should start it's own process, are you seeing anything from that, or getting any errors when calling it in the `handle` method of the button?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors.  The script works independently.  I think the problem might be from the java program continuing before the script is done running which causes some problems downstream.

Comment: Are you consuming the output of the process that is created by exec? You may be running into the following problem indicated in the Process docs: "Because some native platforms only provide limited buffer size for standard input and output streams, failure to promptly write the input stream or read the output stream of the subprocess may cause the subprocess to block, or even deadlock."

Comment: The goal of the script that I'm waiting on is the extract information from an online resource.  This extraction takes a while when the script is run independently (about 5 minutes).  I've been trying to work with `waitFor()` which seems to work for a little while but then I think it times out and continues.

Comment: Perhaps you could try [Jerl](https://github.com/mtshomsky/jerl) instead of trying to spawn a seperate process. "Jerl allows perl to run within the JVM (not having to access any external libs)".  I have never used Jerl.  I expect it probably doesn't work all that well as "Time, funding, and interest have resulted in no further ports."  But, depending upon what you are trying to accomplish, it might be worth a try.  Another alternative is to port the Perl code that another language with better JVM support.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following perl script (windows perl...) where I can extend the sleep call to make it take longer the UI stays responsive while perl is doing it's thing, then the text area is updated with the string returned from perl.

ETA: Probably should have put the readers in a try-with-resources and closed them up...

```
my $x = '';
for (my $i=0; $i <= 1000000; $i++) {
    if ($i % 100000 == 0) {
        sleep(1);
        $x .= '> ' . $i . "\n";
    }
}
print $x;
```

And JavaFX

```
public class PTApp extends Application {

    private TextArea ta;
    private Label lblMsg;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        VBox vb = new VBox(4);
        vb.setPadding(new Insets(4));
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.setText("Run Script");
        btn.setOnAction((ActionEvent event) -> {
            runPerlScript();
        });

        lblMsg = new Label("Ready...");

        ta = new TextArea();
        VBox.setVgrow(ta, Priority.ALWAYS);

        vb.getChildren().addAll(btn, lblMsg, ta);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vb, 600, 650);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Perl Test");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    private void runPerlScript() {
        ta.setText("About to begin...");

        PerlTask pt = new PerlTask();
        lblMsg.textProperty().bind(pt.messageProperty());
        pt.stateProperty().addListener((obs, os, ns) -> {
            //System.out.println("Worker state changed: " + ns.toString());
            if (Worker.State.SUCCEEDED.equals(ns)) {
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    ta.setText(pt.getValue());
                });
            } else if (Worker.State.FAILED.equals(ns)) {
                ta.setText(pt.getException().getMessage());
            }
        });

        Thread th = new Thread(pt);
        th.start();

    }


    public static class PerlTask extends Task<String> {

        @Override
        protected String call() throws Exception {

            updateMessage("About to call Perl...");

            Process pp = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Perl64\\bin\\perl.exe D:\\PerlTest\\perl\\test.pl");

            updateMessage("Perl called, building readers...");

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pp.getInputStream()));
            BufferedReader brE = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pp.getErrorStream()));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("--------Perl Output\n");
            String l;
            while ((l = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l).append("\n");
            }

            updateMessage("Input stream read...");
            sb.append("\n");
            sb.append("--------Perl Errors\n");
            while ((l = brE.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(l).append("\n");
            }

            updateMessage("Error stream read...");

            return sb.toString();

        }

    }

}
```